# Humburger menu button behaviour in CSS

Tags: css, hover

I'm trying to write the *humburger* menu button behaviour for my website. 
What I want is to show the **title** and the **menu button** in the navigation bar. As the user taps the button, I would like the title to hide and the **two menu items** to show.

It doesn't sound complicated, but I can't make it right.

A simplification of the html is

```
<div id="container">
<div id="button">B</div>
<div id="menu1">Menu 1</div>
<div id="title">Title</div>
<div id="menu2">Menu 2</div>

<div style="clear: both;"> </div>
</div>
```

and the css is

```
div {border:1px solid black;}

#menu1, #title, #menu2 {float:left;}
#button {float:right;}

#menu1, #menu2 {
  width:40%;
  display:none;
  }

#title {
  width:80%;
  display:block;
  }


#button:hover + #menu1, 
#button:hover + #menu2 {
  display:block;
  }

#button:hover + #title {
  display:none;
  }
```

Here is a [jsfiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzKhf/2/) of this code.
Where do I go wrong?

Comment: Clicking the `#title` element should make `#menu1` and `#menu2` elements show (and hide the `#title` itself)?

Comment: Thank you @DavidThomas, that would be an easy way out (so I can write rules based on #container, such as `#container:hover > #title {display:none;}`. It's not very elegant, though. Do you think it is possible to trigger the process with #button only?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MBLZx/   Hope this helps you :)